# Expressing a Countable Union of Sets as the Countable Union of Disjoint Sets (e.g. Eliminating Duplicate Intersections)

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Consider a set $E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_{j}$.

How can I re-express $E$ in such a way that all of the contributions to $E_{n}$ are covered only *once.*  Presumably, such a re-expression of $E$ will be some kind of countable union of *disjoint* sets.

The end-goal is to answer the following problem: to show that if $m'$ is any map from the Lebesgue measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ to $[0,\infty]$ which obeys countable additivity and $m'(\emptyset)=0$, then $m'$ also obeys monotonicity and sub-additivity.

Showing that $m'$ obeys monotonicity is easy.  Sub-additivity seems easy at first glance, until you actually have to prove it.  Perhaps there are better ways to do it, but my strategy is to write $E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E'_{j}$ where the $E'_{j}$ are all disjoint "components" of $E$.  Then applying additivity I could expand out $m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E'_{j}\right)$ using additivity (I assume the $E'$ will be  sets formed by multiple set operations of the original $E_{j}$, so applying additivity could be potentially tricky).  Once this expression is obtained, I presume it will be easy to compare it to $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}m'(E_{j})$ and show that it is smaller, hence proving sub-additivity.

**UPDATE**

From the answer below...

\begin{align*}
m'(E)
&=m\left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}E_{j}\right)\\
&=m\left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(E_{j}-\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{j-1}E_{k}\right)\right)&\text{(remove duplicate inersections)}\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}m\left(E_{j}-\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{j-1}E_{k}\right)&\text{(apply assumed additivity)}\\
&\leq\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}m(E_{j}) &\text{(apply aleady proved monotonicity)}
\end{align*}
so that $m'$ is also sub-additive as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define 
$$
F_1=E_1,\ F_2=E_2\setminus E_1,\ \ldots,\ F_{n+1}=E_{n+1}\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^nE_j,\ \ldots
$$

Comment: I figured it'd be something trivial.  I had originally something similar: $$E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_{j}=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(E_{j}-\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{j-1}E_{k}\cap E_{j}\right).$$
I suppose if I had just thought for a little longer, I would've obtained the answer by replacing the intersection with just $E_{k}$.  Instead, I didn't think, and I spent (literally) 2 hours messing with set-theoretic manipulations!  It was terrible.